# Yii Get oldest object from db - findByAttributes

Tags: yii

Using a FindByAttributes query I would like to get the oldest element out of my database.

My Code:

```
$oMemberLocked = MembersLocked::model()->findByAttributes(array(
        'lockedid' => $this->id,
        'request' => 2,
    ));
```

The object MembersLocked has a attribute 'date'.

How can I get the element with the largest date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order the query by ascending date.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->order = 'date ASC';
$oMemberLocked = MembersLocked::model()->findByAttributes(array(
    'lockedid' => $this->id,
    'request' => 2,
), $criteria);
```